# Change raw query join into laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two models:

```
$modelMain = "SearchPages"; //table_name : search_pages
$modelSites = "Site"; // table_name : sites
```

I initially had a below query for getting count from only one model `$modelMain`:

```
$records = $modelMain::
        select(DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT {$columnRecordedOn}) as records_count"))
        ->groupBy($columnRecordedOn, $columnSiteId)
        ->get();
```

Now, I need to join it with 2nd model `$modelSites` whoese table name is `sites` in order to check status column in `sites` if its 1.

I modified the query to:

```
$records = $modelMain::
    select(DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT {$columnRecordedOn}) as records_count"))
    ->join('sites','search_pages.site_id','=','sites.site_id') //added this
    ->where('sites.status','=','1') // and this
    ->groupBy($columnRecordedOn, $columnSiteId)
    ->get();
```

All working fine but as you can see I am using table name `sites` directly in `join()` and in `where()` instead I must use model name I believe.

How can I convert this query to proper Laravel Eloquent?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can use "with" method to get related model

Site Model

```
class Site extends Eloquent {

    public function searchpages()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('SearchPage','site_id','site_id');
    }

}
```

SearchPage Model

```
class SearchPage extends Eloquent {

    public function site()
    {
    return $this->belongTo('Site','site_id','site_id');
    }

}
```

$records = SearchPage::with('site')->get();

as per your need

```
$records = SearchPage::
       select(DB::raw("COUNT(DISTINCT {$columnRecordedOn}) as records_count"))
    ->whereHas('site' => function($q){
                                        $q->where('status','1');
                                    })
    ->groupBy($columnRecordedOn, $columnSiteId)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Kamlesh.bar , but its not filtering according to the status, however does giving any error.

Comment: @Fahad i have put wrong name 'sites' instead it should be 'site' according to function name in SearchPage Model. edited answer now

Comment: I had corrected that... it still returning all records.

Comment: it should work. can you please paste this below $queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
print_r($last_query);exit;

Comment: Is there something like `where(...with(...)...)` ?

Comment: Well I have `Common::showQuery(1);` for showing query. its returning `select * from `sites` where `sites`.`site_id` in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and status=1`

Comment: that's look okay. don't you get preferred result with this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76436/discussion-between-kamlesh-bar-and-fahad).

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at using the relationships in Eloquent, you should declare the relationship in your two models, something like:

```
class SearchPages extends Eloquent {

    public function sites()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('sites');
    }

}
```

For more on Eloquent and relationships look at this reference:
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships