# Laravel5 Eloquent Query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel and am stuck with a query. I have ShopCustomer table which shop_id and customer_id in it.There are multiple entries of shop_id and different customer_id in it. It has many to many relationship.

I have a shop_id = 2. I want to find Customers by their name = 'Mat'. I have tried my code with JOIN clause. I am looking to convert the following query into Eloquent Query builder and want to use Eager Loading.

```
$customers = \DB::table('shop_cust')
            ->join('customers', 'customers.customer_id', '=', 'shop_cust.customer_id')
            ->select('shop_cust.total_amount', 'customers.*')
            ->where('customers.name', 'LIKE', 'Mat')
            ->where('shop_cust.shop_id', '=', '2')
            ->get();

dd($customers);
```

This is what I have tried.

```
$customers = ShopCust::with(['customer' => function ($query)
 use ($customerName) {
      $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $customerName . '%');
 }])->where('shop_id','=', $shopId)->get();
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: similar question i have answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29913238/change-raw-query-join-into-laravel-eloquent/29914943#29914943

Comment: @kamlesh.bar Hi Kamlesh, I have tried a lot of code from last few days. It would be great if you could answer this.

Comment: basically you have two tables rights shopCustomer and Customer right?

Comment: Three tables. ShopCust, Shop and Customer. Shop Table will have shop_id(primary) with shop details. Customer will have customer_id(primary). ShopCust will have both shop_id and cust_id (composite key) with total_amount, etc. It's many to many relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ShopCustomer Model

```
class ShopCustomer Eloquent {

    public function customers()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('Customer','customer_id','customer_id');
    }


    public function shops()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('Shop','shop_id','shop_id');
    }

}
```

Customer Model

```
class Customer Eloquent {

    public function customer_shop()
    {
    return $this->belongToMany('ShopCustomer','customer_id','customer_id');
    }

}
```

Shop Model

```
class Shop Eloquent {

        public function shop_customer()
        {
        return $this->belongToMany('ShopCustomer','shop_id','shop_id');
        }

    }
```

your query

```
$customers = ShopCustomer::
    ->with(arra('customer' => function($q) use ($customerName){
                                        $query->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $customerName . '%');
                                    }))
    ->where('shop_id','=', $shopId)->get();
```

Comment: did you get this message from above query.?? nowhere i have used shop_customer_id !!! http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables

Comment: If customer is not there, then it gives me "customer":[ ]. If customer name doesn't match, then I don't want that row.

Comment: you can use orWhere or whereHas method.

Comment: Any help @kamlesh.bar ? Where to use whereHas method?

Comment: This solved my issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29591931/merge-with-and-wherehas-in-laravel-5

Comment: How can I search by both first_name and last_name? I tried orWhere but it gives me users = [ ] if both doesn't match.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described is a many-to-many relationship between Shop and Customer. Your shop_cust table is just the pivot table for the relationship. Unless you have some special functionality for shop_cust, it doesn't need a model defined for it.

```
class Shop extends Model {
    public function customers() {
        return $this->belongToMany('Customer', 'shop_cust');
    }
}

class Customer extends Model {
    public function shops() {
        return $this->belongToMany('Shop', 'shop_cust');
    }
}
```

With this definition, your code would look like:

```
$shop = Shop::find(2);
$customers = $shop->customers()->where('name', 'LIKE', 'Mat');
```

There is no real need to eager load here since you're only looking at the customers for one specific shop.

### Edit

If you have extra fields on the pivot table you want to access, you can do that as well. First, you add access to the extra fields using the `withPivot()` method on the relationships:

```
class Shop extends Model {
    public function customers() {
        return $this->belongToMany('Customer', 'shop_cust')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
    }
}

class Customer extends Model {
    public function shops() {
        return $this->belongToMany('Shop', 'shop_cust')->withPivot('foo', 'bar');
    }
}
```

Now, you can access the data through the pivot model attribute:

```
foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    echo $customer->pivot->foo;
    echo $customer->pivot->bar;
}
```

Documentation for working with pivot tables [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables).

Comment: I am looking for ShopCust model because it has more data than just shop_id and cust_id.

Comment: @Chopra I have updated my answer to provide some more information for that situation. Since you seem to have solved your issues for now, you may not want to change your code, but I thought you might be interested in the information.